# Why i get a cy.origin problem if I am navigate just once into a page

Tags: cypress, cross-domain

I am trying to check if I am on the right page but I get this error: `expected '' to include http://localhost:4200`
And this is my code

```
`cy.visit('https://login');
  cy.get('#username').type(username);
  cy.get('#password').type(password);
  cy.get('#kc-login').click()
  cy.wait(7000)
  cy.url().should('include', 'http://localhost:4200/machines')`
```

And I do not understand why my string is empty

If I am not using this cy.visit() I get a cy.origin() problem and I also do not understand why I get this cy.origin() problem because I am on the localhost. I am not navigate into another page.
I do not want to use cy.origin() anymore (I do not undesrant why I even have to use it) and I found the `experimentalSkipDomainInjection` but is still not working
I really do not know what to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo in your `cy.visit()`.

If you are on `localhost`, you should specify the full URL

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost/login');
cy.get('#username').type(username);
cy.get('#password').type(password);
cy.get('#kc-login').click()
  
//cy.wait(7000)  // don't do this

cy.url({timeout: 7000}).should('include', 'http://localhost:4200/machines')
```

Comment: So I am using keyclock, so the authentication is on another URL

`
"Keycloak": {
      "Url": "https://auth-ci.....com",
      "Realm": "localhost",
`
I tried to use the login method in commands and try to call it in beforeEach and to visit the machine page  in it blocks but still is not working

Answer (score 2):

If you struggle with keycloak, install this plugin [cypress-keycloak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak)

Your question does not have enough details to answer exactly, but this is the pattern to use

```js
describe('thing', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login({
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      username: 'babangsund',
      password: 'bacon',
      client_id: 'frontend',
      redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
    });
    
    cy.loginOTP({                               // or login with OTP
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      username: 'babangsund',
      password: 'bacon',
      client_id: 'frontend',
      redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
      otp_secret: 'OZLDC2HZKM3QUC...', // e.g. 32 chars
      otp_credential_id: '5e231f20-8ca7-35e1-20a694b60181ca9', // e.g. 36 chars
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.logout({
      root: 'https://keycloak.babangsund.com',
      realm: 'stage',
      // using Keycloak < 18.0.0:
      // redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
      // using Keycloak >= 18.0.0:
      post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://babangsund.com/',
    });
  });
})
```